# Unable to delete rows in datatable multiple times

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I currently have a primefaces datatable table with a conditional delete button that will delete the row if clicked. Clicking on it the first time works. It would delete the row and the table will be refreshed with the new table. When I try to delete something from the table again, the table would refresh itself with no entries. If I update the table using one of the buttons that I created, the table would show up again with the entry that I tried to delete still there. Looking into it, I see that the method in action is being called when I deleted the first one successfully. However, when I try it again, the method is not being invoked. Why isn't it?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
<p:dataTable id="carTable" var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                        Car Table
                    </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{car.id}">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Year" sortBy="#{car.year}">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Brand" sortBy="#{car.brand}">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Color" sortBy="#{car.color}">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Delete Option">
                <p:commandLink action="#{dtBasicView.deleteCar(car)}"
                    update="@form" rendered="#{car.isWhite}" value="Delete" ajax="true">
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And the bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="dtBasicView")
@ViewScoped
public class BasicView implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Car selectedCar;
    private List<Car> cars;
    private List<Car> oneHundredCars;
    private int numberOfcars=0;

    @ManagedProperty("#{carService}")
    private CarService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        oneHundredCars = service.createCars(100);
    }

    public void setNumberOfcars(String num) {
        this.numberOfcars = Integer.parseInt(num);
        cars = oneHundredCars.subList(0, numberOfcars);
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setService(CarService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public Car getSelectedCar() {
        return selectedCar;
    }

    public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
    }


    public boolean getIsEmpty() {
        return cars == null || cars.isEmpty();
    }

    public void deleteCar(Car car) {
        cars.remove(car);
        int size = cars.size();
        setNumberOfcars(""+size);
    }
}
```

A little update: I still haven't fixed my problem. I have shifted some things around so that the list is not resizeable. Now whenever I click on the second delete commandlink, the whole datatable gets refreshed with new random data.

Another update: It appears as if it is calling the @PostConstruct again after hitting the second delete. By doing so, it is recreating a whole new set of arrays of cars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending the whole day yesterday trying to figure out why this is happening, I have finally fixed it. I have changed the commandlink to commandbutton and neither of those changes worked. What worked for me was instead of letting the button be an ajax submit, it would instead be a non-ajax submit. I still do not know why this worked, so if anyone can explain it would be greatly helpful.